# Select Case query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to SQL and in the process of developing query, with the to replicate part of an ETL process.

A billing code1 = bf, is then set to debt code 1. If billing field (debt code) exceeds 100 characters then add '*' as prefix.

However query will fall down because billing code1  = bf returns a single resultset to a debt code1 that returns large resultset.

```
select 
    case when len(format) > 100 then left(format, 100) + '*' 
    else format end as format
from (select case when exists (select _hs_eb_code1 from hbl_cat where hs_eb_code = 'bf)
                  then tbm_bllgrp._hs_eb_det1 end) as format
from tbm_bllgrp
```

Ideas welcomed.

Comment: Why can't you just use a `WHERE` clause in the subquery?

Comment: SQL server and will consider the use of where clause.

Comment: so - you want to apply len(format) > 100 ONLY for rows that have a hs_eb_code = 'bf' ? What is the join between tbm_bllgrp and hbl_cat?

Comment: Suggest posting your schema of your two tables, and your expected output. As it stands, you've got a derived table named `format`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
case when len(format) > 100 then left(format, 100) + '*' 
else format end as format
from tbm_bllgrp b
    inner join hbl_cat hc on hc._hs_eb_code1 = b._hs_eb_det1
```

This is just a guess since I don't have your exactl schema and expected output, but I hope this gives you some ideas